# LibGdx - need help on Screen class

Tags: android, libgdx

I've been using `libgdx` for the past 3 weeks..
I created two screens referencing to a game:

```
public class Game extends Game {

TitleScreen titleScreen;
SplashScreen splashScreen;

@Override
public void create() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    titleScreen = new TitleScreen(this);
    splashScreen = new SplashScreen(this);
    setScreen(splashScreen);

}
```

}

and

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

Game game;

public SplashScreen(Game game) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.game = game;
    }


@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 1f, 1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        game.splashScreen.dispose();
        game.setScreen(game.titlescreen);
    }

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

How do I dispose the `splashscreen` entirely?  When I called the `game.setscreen(game.splashscreen)` in `titlescreen` class, it resume the `splashscreen`;.  I'm expecting to set a new `splashscreen`..

Comment: Please correct the code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new splash screen every time you want to show a splash from the beginning:

```
game.setScreen(new SplashScreen(game));
```

Comment: This is very bad to do if it's a screen that you intend on going back to frequently.  Screens are large complex objects where instantiation and garbage collecting is not something that you should be relying on.  What you should be doing is having the core setup logic set within show(), which is called every time you switch to that screen, and you should have tear down and releasing of certain assets within hide()